# Why is Python saying pow only has 2 arguments

Tags: python, syntax-error

Why is python telling me "TypeError: pow expected 2 arguments, got 3" despite it working in IDLE (sometimes it tells me that in IDLE as well)? im simply doing `pow(a,b,c)`. my program is very short and i do not change the definition of `pow` at any time since i need to use it for some exponentiation.

NOTE: This is the `pow` from `__builtin__`, not `Math`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Built-in `pow` takes two or three arguments. If you do `from math import *` then it is replaced by math's `pow`, which takes only two arguments. My recommendation is to do `import math`, or explicitly list functions you use in import list. Similar issue happens with `open` vs. `os.open`.

Comment: ah... maybe that's why. thanks!!!!!

err... would an import from another file affect it? im importing another program i wrote which also has `from math import *`

Comment: @calccrypto: If you're importing the another program with `from p import *` then yes. Use `import p` or list explicitly `from p import [...]`.

Comment: If you need to call the builtin `pow` after `from math import *`, you can use the explicit form `__builtins__.pow()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using math functions a lot and the three parameter version of pow infrequently a way around this in python 2.7 is to import `__builtin__` and call `__builtin__`.pow for the 3 paramete

Comment: There should be two underscore characters either side of 'builitin' in both cases but the formatting interpreted that as bold font - not sure what to do about thaat.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/functions.html

> `pow(x, y[, z])` Return x to the power
>   y; if z is present, return x to the
>   power y, modulo z (computed more
>   efficiently than pow(x, y) % z). The
>   two-argument form pow(x, y) is
>   equivalent to using the power
>   operator: x**y.
>
> The arguments must have numeric types.
>   With mixed operand types, the coercion
>   rules for binary arithmetic operators
>   apply. For int and long int operands,
>   the result has the same type as the
>   operands (after coercion) unless the
>   second argument is negative; in that
>   case, all arguments are converted to
>   float and a float result is delivered.
>   For example, 10**2 returns 100, but
>   10**-2 returns 0.01. (This last
>   feature was added in Python 2.2. In
>   Python 2.1 and before, if both
>   arguments were of integer types and
>   the second argument was negative, an
>   exception was raised.) **If the second
>   argument is negative, the third
>   argument must be omitted. If z is
>   present, x and y must be of integer
>   types, and y must be non-negative.**
>   (This restriction was added in Python
>   2.2. In Python 2.1 and before, floating 3-argument pow() returned
>   platform-dependent results depending
>   on floating-point rounding accidents.)

Perhaps you're violating the bold portion?

Comment: no. im sure that all the values are positive integers

edit: yep. a,b,c = 9, 4, 225